# Signal Upstream to choose different path onError - Spring Reactor

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following code,

```
ClassA {
   Mono<Integer> execute(ListElement listElement) {
   //returns mono on success and throwable on failure
  } 
}

Flux.fromIterable(list)
.flatMap( listElement -> classA.execute(listElement)
.doOnError(throwable -> Mono.just(500)).flatMap(......)
```

when a call to **execute** fails, is it possible to process the elements from the source in a different way? i.e not to call the same method which threw an exception for one of the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this cannot be done as it goes against the reactive manifest.

> "If a Publisher signals either onError or onComplete on a Subscriber,
>   that Subscriber’s Subscription MUST be considered cancelled."
>
> https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm